# How to loop through 5 UITableView cells based on the original cell tapped first

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that lists some data in a tableview, in cells.  I want the user to be able to select a table view cell, any one, and have the app cycle through the 5 lower cells.  Here is what I have so far:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    [self fetchCellsToProcess:indexPath];

}
```

Here is the fetchCellsToProcess: method:

```
-(void)fetchCellsToProcess:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    for (int cellsToProcess = 0; cellsToProcess < 5; cellsToProcess++) {
         //process each cell
         //...
   }
}
```

I need use the indexPath to get its indexPath.row.  Then add 5 to that indexPath.row and only process the tweets between indexPath.row passed in and indexPath.row+5.  What programming logic should I use to cycle through cells x -> x+5?

Comment: Hey who down-voted my question and why?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` here: that's part of the presentation logic, while you are working on the model-level logic here.

Look at your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and see from where does the text of the cell's labels come. Usually it is an `NSArray` or some other collection. Your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method should go directly to that same collection, and grab the info from there.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct approach to achieve this as dasblinkenlight mentioned 

but there is a work around which works for me.

Please follow below approach:

Create your custom button within your custom cell

Create your custom cell class and put button(change type to custom ) do necessary connection custom cell class 

 create and connect action method named "actionSelectedCell" as below from that button in class you are implementing this logic.

And cellForRowAtIndexPath cell.customButton.text = data from your array or dictionary

```
- (IBAction)actionSelectedCell:(UIButton *)sender {

// below code for getting selected cell row and its section

UIView *view = sender.superview;
while (view && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]]) view = view.superview;

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;
indexPathForSelectedCell = [self.tableViewListViewVC indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"cell is in section %d, row %d", indexPathForSelectedCell.section, indexPathForSelectedCell.row);// so now you are getting indexpath for selected cell

 // now you can create simple loop logic to get required data and do whatever you like post it to something or store it for any other use

NSString *strFifthCellContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataArray ObjectAtIndex:indexPathForSelectedCell.row+5]]; // in this way you can get data from any cell




}
```

Comment: Its the 'simple logic' that's got me stumped. Its turning out to be not so simple.  I have to count 5 cell indexpath.rows from the selected one and get their data. Im thinking because for-loop may not be the best option for this.